# Creating one instance from each subclass of a super class

Tags: c++

Say I have a base class `Base`, and some derived classes `D1`, `D2`, `D3`, which all have constructors with same parameters.

Can I have a function template, which takes all derived class types as template parameters, to create one object from each type, cast to base pointer, then return an array of base pointers?

Something like this:

```
(Base*)[n] baseList = createChildren<Base, D1, D2, D3, …>();
```

Comment: Yes, you can have.

Comment: You can't return a raw C-style array like that. But you can return a pointer to a `new[]`'ed array, or return a `std::array` or `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 1):

To implement `createChildren()`, a [template parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) can be used:

```
template <typename Base, typename... Class>
std::array<Base*, sizeof... (Args)> createChildren();
```

Please, note that I changed the suggested signature of OP to return a `std::array` instead of the `(Base*)[n]`. I believe in any case that `(Base*)[n]` is a pointer to an array of `n` `Base` instances. That sounds wrong. However, even if OP meant instead `Base*[n]` (an array of `n` `Base` pointers), this is a problem as arrays cannot be returned by value. This problem does not exist for `std::array<>`.

The implementation of `createChildren()` (I called it `createDerived()`) can be done quite compactly using the `std::array` constructor with aggregate initialization:

```
template <typename Base, typename... Args> 
std::array<Base*, sizeof... (Args)> createDerived()
{
  return std::array<Base*, sizeof... (Args)>{ new Args() ... };
}
```

Thereby, [sizeof... (Args)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof...) is used to determine the size of the array to return.

The initialization is done with `{ new Args() ... }` via aggregate initialization.

Thereby, a [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) is used which makes the processing of template parameter packs very handy. It was introduced in C++17. Before C++17, this would have been a more tedious task — probably something with recursive helper templates…

Calling the template function with `<Base, A, B C>` will result in:

```
return std::array<Base*, 3>{ new A(), new B(), new C() };
```

[**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d2903a291b57a08):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <array>

template <typename Base, typename... Args> 
std::array<Base*, sizeof... (Args)> createDerived()
{
  return std::array<Base*, sizeof... (Args)>{ new Args() ... };
}

struct Base {
  virtual ~Base() = default;
  virtual const char* whoAmI() const = 0;
};

#define DEFINE(CLASS) \
struct CLASS: Base { \
  virtual ~CLASS() = default; \
  virtual const char* whoAmI() const override { return #CLASS; } \
}

DEFINE(A);
DEFINE(B);
DEFINE(C);

int main()
{
  // test createDerived()
  auto pClasses
    = createDerived<Base, A, B, C>();
  // show result
  for (const Base* pClass : pClasses) {
    std::cout << pClass->whoAmI() << '\n';
  }
}
```

Output:

```
A
B
C
```

---

Before I became aware that the size of the returned array is known at compile time, I used `std::vector` instead of `std::array`.

The sample doesn't look that different if `std::array` is replaced by `std::vector` except that operator `sizeof... ()` is not needed.

[**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a9f384913ecb25a1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

template <typename Base, typename... Args> 
std::vector<Base*> createDerived()
{
  return std::vector<Base*>{ new Args() ... };
}

struct Base {
  virtual ~Base() = default;
  virtual const char* whoAmI() const = 0;
};

#define DEFINE(CLASS) \
struct CLASS: Base { \
  virtual ~CLASS() = default; \
  virtual const char* whoAmI() const override { return #CLASS; } \
}

DEFINE(A);
DEFINE(B);
DEFINE(C);

int main()
{
  // test createDerived()
  std::vector<Base*> pClasses
    = createDerived<Base, A, B, C>();
  // show result
  for (const Base* pClass : pClasses) {
    std::cout << pClass->whoAmI() << '\n';
  }
}
```

Output:

```
A
B
C
```

The usage of raw pointers and `new` annoyed me a bit. Hence, I modified the above sample to use `std::unique_ptr<Base>` instead (which manages the destruction by itself when appropriate).

[**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/66f702376a07c88a):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

template <typename Base, typename... Args> 
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> createDerived()
{
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> refClasses;
  ([&]() { refClasses.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Args>()); }(), ...);
  return refClasses;
}

struct Base {
  virtual ~Base() = default;
  virtual const char* whoAmI() = 0;
};

#define DEFINE(CLASS) \
struct CLASS: Base { \
  virtual ~CLASS() = default; \
  virtual const char* whoAmI() override { return #CLASS; } \
}

DEFINE(A);
DEFINE(B);
DEFINE(C);

int main()
{
  // test createDerived()
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> refClasses
    = createDerived<Base, A, B, C>();
  // show result
  for (const std::unique_ptr<Base>& refClass : refClasses) {
    std::cout << refClass->whoAmI() << '\n';
  }
}
```

Output:

```
A
B
C
```

I must admit I struggled a bit with the initialization of the `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>>`. In the case of the `std::vector`, it's rather list initialization than aggregate initialization. In a list initialization, the arguments are copied. This is not a problem for raw pointers (`Base*`) but it's a problem for `std::unique_ptr` which are not copyable but moveable only.

Thus, I used the trick with the immediately called lambda to achieve a sequence of `emplace_back()` calls.

Comment: Just note that the code shown is making use of [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) to unpack the template parameter pack, which requires C++17 or later. If you are using C++11 or C++14, the code will have to be adjusted accordingly to unpack the template parameter pack in a different slightly more complex way.